# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch error MATLAB

Tags: matlab

i am trying to run a series of equations by calling certain data points from my matrix over a series of combinations.  I am essentially comparing each data set against the others, one at a time, over a series of different errors (the errors are the psivct array).

i am getting a "subscripted assignment dimension mismatch" error for the final line of my code and i don't know what to do about it....?  I have done my best to comment out my code for clarity...

it works fine when i am only comparing two sets, but when i add the third, i get this error.  Any insight?

Thanks again in advance for any help :)

```
datamatrix=[674 0 6049 46489;760 180 90735 120980; 650 0 12500 61000]; %data points velocity,
heading, x location, y location
psivct=[-90, -45, 0, 45, 90];%degrees degrees of error 
psidot=3; %degrees/sec rate of error change
d=500; %distance apart for a problem, in feet
Nr_AC=3; %number of aircrafts in sector


for c1 = 1:size(psivct,2)
    psi1=psivct(c1); %for loop to run through array of blunder errors

    for c2=1:Nr_AC-1; %for loop to account for all pairs and avoid same pairs twice

        for c3=c2+1:Nr_AC; %for loop to help avoid account for hte same pairs twice


k1=datamatrix(c2,1).*cosd(datamatrix(c2,2)+psi1)-datamatrix(c2,1)*cosd(datamatrix(c3,2));

k2=((datamatrix(c2,1)/psidot).*(sind(datamatrix(c2,2)+psi1)-sind(datamatrix(c2,2))))
cosd(datamatrix(c2,2)+psi1)*datamatrix(c2,1).*(psi1./psidot)+datamatrix(c2,3)-datamatrix(c3,3);

k3=datamatrix(c2,1).*sind(datamatrix(c2,2)+psi1)-datamatrix((c3),1)*sind(datamatrix((c3),2));

k4=(datamatrix(c2,1)/psidot)*(cosd(datamatrix(c2,2))-cosd(datamatrix(c2,2)+psi1))
sind(datamatrix(c2,2)+psi1)*datamatrix(c2,1).*(psi1./psidot)+datamatrix(c2,4)-datamatrix(c3,4);

k5=k1.^2+k3.^2; %"a" in the polynomial
k6=2*(k1.*k2+k3.*k4); %"b" in the polynomial
k7=k3.^2+k4.^2-500; %"c" in the polynomial
p = [k5 k6 k7]; % creating hte polynomial
r = roots(p); %solving for roots
rr(:,c1,c2,c3)=real(r)/60 %getting real answers
end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: can you show the output of a whos just before that last line generating the error?

Comment: Your variables are:

Nr_AC       c3          k1          k4          k7          psidot      rr          
c1          d           k2          k5          p           psivct      
c2          datamatrix  k3          k6          psi1        r

Comment: oh I mean what do you get when you type 'whos' in the Command window?

Comment: You get an error because your `r` is empty when `c1=3, c2=1, c3=3`. `r` is empty because `p=[0 0 -500]`, it has no roots. From here, you have to take on the problem. Also, this is basic debugging. You need to learn this to solve your problems more efficiently.

Comment: Nr_AC  1x1     8  double     
c      20x1    2354  cell                
c1     1x1     8  double     c2     1x1     8  double              
c3     1x1     8  double
d      1x1     8  double
datamatrix  3x4     96  double            
k1     1x1     8  double
k2     1x1     8  double  k3     1x1     8  double
k4     1x1     8  double
k5     1x1     8  double
k6     1x1     8  double
k7     1x1     8  double 
p      1x3    24  double              
psi1   1x1     8  double
psidot 1x1     8  double
psivct 1x5    40  double  
r      0x1    0  double
rr     4-D    288  double

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar  i appreciate the help, Parag!  However, i think it's more helpful to be supportive towards each other, especially for a beginner that is learning to code in Matlab.  The scientific community should be a non-threatening place where questions can be freely asked and we can all learn from each other!!!!  I'm sure in time, i will be able to solve my problems without help and more efficiently :-)  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the `r` vector: it sometimes is empty because the polynomial doesn't have roots. Then `r` is a 0x1 vector, and you're assigning it to a 2x1 vector (`r(:,c1,c2,c3)` is a 2x1 vector because the first time you assign `r` to it, Matlab creates the matrix `rr` and initializes its size).

You would need a check on the existence of roots before you do the assignment. Something like

```
if (~isempty(r))
  rr(:,c1,c2,c3)=real(r)/60; %getting real answers
end
```

As a general rule, it would be good to figure out how the size of rr before starting your loops, and initializing rr. It results in better performance, and 'cleaner' code, since Matlab is not trying to resize the 4-D matrix all the time.

Also, be careful in your lines for k2 and k4, the sind and cosd are not taken into account right now. If you wanted to continue the line (and multiply the first line by the second, you should do:

```
k2=((datamatrix(c2,1)/psidot).*(sind(datamatrix(c2,2)+psi1)-sind(datamatrix(c2,2)))) * ...
cosd(datamatrix(c2,2)+psi1)*datamatrix(c2,1).*(psi1./psidot)+datamatrix(c2,3)-datamatrix(c3,3);
```

with `*` or `.*` depending on what you want to accomplish

Comment: thanks Etienne - I really appreciate the support and effort in the answer!  It worked and no more error.  Thanks!

Comment: @CaitlinSurakitbanharn Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer helped solving your issue, please mark it as accepted! Happy coding!

Comment: This will create empty sub-matrices within `rr` since `c1, c2, c3` will keep on increasing. If `r` is empty, there will be an empty submatrix in `rr`. Just remember that.

Comment: Mmm, no, it will just leave the components of `rr` that correspond to the cases with no roots at the initial value. Maybe you can consider initializing your array to a special value that you can recognize to be the initial one, and then it provides you with a convenient way to check directly in `rr` if a case has roots or not.